# should I use "for free download" or "for free downloading"?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds, nominalization

I was going to write that something is ready for free download.
But maybe for free downloading is the right grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Without considering the cost options, the more natural formulation is "*for download*", whether "*ready for download*" or "*available for download*".

So, writing "*for free download*" is fine, but "*for free downloading*" sounds unusual. You might also consider alternative wording such as "*available for download at no cost*", or "*available for download (free)*".

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say "The download is free", or "For a free download" Either way, it will still be grammatically correct, but it may not sound as correct as other wordings.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

> free download is available

few example could be found here: http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/available/1.html

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.